# microsoft azure free plan - minimum credits to use

Tags: azure

I have activated a free plan on microsoft AZURE that includes 170 EUR to use for a month.

I have just activated a test service account for BLOB storage, sendgrid, CDN and active directory, without using them yet, but I spend about 7,36 EUR daily. 
There is a way to know what type of services  consume those credits with free plan ?
Maybe this free plan has a mininum of credit daily to use ?

Comment: Did you look at your subscription https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions where you can see the current charge and download the detail ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's no free plan. You received to 170 EUR to spent the way you want, for a month. After that, or if you consume those 170 EUR, it will charge your credit card.